# JQuery Select Element On Changing Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a page with a changing partial view.  In the main view, how do you select a model property of the partial view when it updates?

The gist of the main page is something like this:

```
<script ...etc >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#renew").click(function () {
            $("#to-renew").load(...etc);
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <input type="button" id="renew" value="Renew" />
    <div id="to-renew"></div>
</div>
```

The partial view that gets "renewed" every click brings new data from the database, such like:

```
<div id="to-renew">
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MyProperty)
</div>
```

What I need to do is, for each refresh, select this new updated property from the main page, such like:

```
<script ...etc >
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#renew").click(function () {
            $("#to-renew").load(...etc);
            alert('@Model.MyProperty');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Except this code will only ever alert the first value, and never the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Model.MyProperty` is rendered when displaying the page, so it never gets renewed after the initial load. If the div's content is being updated correctly, just get it's content with javascript and display:

```
alert($("#to-renew").html());
```

Or if it's a hidden input:

```
alert($("#to-renew input").val());
```